# SQL Query Best techniques to get MAX data from a foreign key linked table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written two queries however feel they are inefficient.

I have two queries, one which prepares the data (the data was originally from a old fox pro db and the dates etc where nvarchars, so I convert them to dates etc) the second which collates all of the data ready to be exported to a csv and eventually the csv is sent to a web service.

So the first query...

I have a table of people and a table of placements (placements being a job that they have had) the placements table will have lots of different rows for a single person and I need only the latest (based on start and end date), is the below the most efficient way of doing this?

PersonCode = unique id for the person, Code = unique id for the placement

```
    SELECT * FROM Person c
      LEFT JOIN 
        (
           SELECT MAX(StartDate) AS StartDate, MAX(EndDate) AS EndDate, MAX(Code) AS Code, PersonCode
            FROM PersonPlacement
        GROUP BY PersonCode
    ) cp ON c.PersonCode = cp.PersonCode
  LEFT JOIN PersonPlacement cp2 ON cp.Code = cp2.Code
```

So my second query is below...

The second query reads from the first query and needs to do the following:

- Get only unique candidates based on last contact date (the original data had dupes)
- Get the latest placement
- Get Resume data
- Only get people that are not currently in a job based on start and end date of placement
- If they are in a job that is ending soon then show them

See query below...

```
SELECT *
FROM Pre_PersonView c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT  PersonCode, Code, row_number() over(partition by PersonCode order by StartDate desc) as rn
    FROM Pre_PersonView

) pj ON c.PersonCode = pj.PersonCode AND pj.rn = 1

LEFT JOIN Pre_PersonView cp ON pj.Code = cp.Code

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT  PersonCode, row_number() over(partition by PersonCode order by LastContactDate desc) as rn
    FROM Person
) uc  ON c.PersonCode = uc.PersonCode AND uc.rn = 1

LEFT JOIN [PersonResumeText] ct ON c.PersonId = ct.PersonId

WHERE c.PersonCode NOT IN
(
    SELECT pcv.PersonCode
     FROM Pre_PersonView pcv
      WHERE pcv.Department IN ('x','y','z')
       AND pcv.StartDate <= GETDATE() 
       AND (CASE WHEN pcv.EndDate = '1899-12-30' THEN GETDATE() + 1 ELSE pcv.EndDate END) > GETDATE()
)

     AND  DATEDIFF(DAY, ISNULL((CASE WHEN cp.StartDate = '0216-07-22' THEN '2016-07-22' ELSE cp.StartDate END), GETDATE() -365), ISNULL((CASE WHEN cp.EndDate = '1899-12-30' THEN NULL ELSE cp.EndDate END), GETDATE() + 1)) 
     > 
     (CASE WHEN cp.Department IN ('x','y','z') THEN 365 ELSE 2 END)
```

Again my question here is this the most efficient way to be doing this?

Comment: In the first query you should probably make use of a row_number function to get the placement row you're interested in. I know you know how to use it because it's in your second query :) You should also look to simplify some of the logic in your second query to make it more readable before you start thinking about improving the efficiency, because it's hard to work with right now. Just as an example, `CASE WHEN pcv.EndDate = '1899-12-30' THEN GETDATE() + 1 ELSE pcv.EndDate END) > GETDATE()` is the same as `(pcv.EndDate > GETDATE() OR pcv.EndDate = '1899-12-30')`, which reads better IMHO

Comment: Good point on the (pcv.EndDate > GETDATE() OR pcv.EndDate = '1899-12-30') part, that is much easier to read thank you. I will take a stab at the row_number for the first query